# Python Pandas Dataframes in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few dataframes and I would like to concat them in a special manor.

We have 2 tables:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| "Cat" | "Dog" |
| "Dino" | "Fish" |

I would like to create a structure where headers from each table are getting one header like this:

[image]

How is it done with Pandas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `df1` is your Table1 and `df2` is Table2, then:

```py
out = pd.concat({"Numbers": df1, "Center": df2}, axis=1)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  Numbers    Center      
        A  B      C     D
0       1  2    Cat   Dog
1       3  4   Dino  Fish
```